# How to Echo a Distinct Count in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, count, echo, distinct

I have a Mysql that returns a count of items we have in stock

select count(distinct style) from bottles

I want to echo that value out to my website.  I tried.

```
    <?php 
#///////////////////////////////////
#// Show Amount of Bottles
#///////////////////////////////////
$distinct = mysql_query("select count(distinct style) from bottles", $con);
$num_rows = count($distinct);
echo "$num_rows Bottles In Stock";
?> as of <?php print date('l F jS, Y', time()-86400);
```

But its only showing me the value of 1?   Can someone point me in the right direction?

Also if I would like to have one statement echo multiple rows how can i do this?

Item Name  |  Style  |  Location

So I would like to echo on our site:

As of today we have 400 bottles of beer in stock  X different styles from Y locations?

Thanks in advance for any help.  I just started teaching myself php and mysql about a month ago.

Ryan

Comment: You're using `SELECT count(...`, which returns a single row with the count in it. You need to retrieve the result set using something like `$row = mysql_fetch_array($distinct)`, and then the count will be in `$row[0]`.

Comment: hello. sth like this: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo $row['attribute']; }

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, don't use `mysql_query`. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed. If you follow a [guide to PHP](http://www.phptherightway.com/) and use something better like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) you'll learn the correct way of doing things, not some anachronism from the 1990s.

Comment: Your query will return one row only with the quantity of different bottles style.
Also, to retrieve each row with specific details of each bottles, your query should be "SELECT item_name, style, location FROM bottles". (I'm assuming those columns are in your table.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count(distinct style)` is the only row and column returned. Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select count(distinct style) from bottles", $con);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$num_rows = $row[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not counting the number of rows , try to use this piece of code instead

```
$distinct = mysql_query("select count(distinct style) from bottles", $con);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($distinct); //num rows
echo count($num_rows);
// For every row in result make an object
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($distinct)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```